# Is it safe to delete some snapshots from jv_snapshot for Javers?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, javers

We have been tracking changes for some of the collections with Javers (Spring Boot and MongoDB).

We want to delete following type of snapshots manually:

1. All snapshots created for a particular collection.
2. All snapshots created for a particular field inside a collection

Is it safe to delete these type of snapshots manually or could it create some issue?